# After upgrade Artifactory to version 6.16 - The local repositories can not be seen in the artifact repository browser

Tags: artifactory

We upgraded the Artifactory 6.5.9 to 6.16, and now the local repositories (That exist and function) can not be seen in the Artifact Repository tree.  I only see the remote repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your repository browser is filtered only to remote repositories. Did you check that the list is not filtered? See the attached screenshot and make sure that the repository type is not checked with Remote or Cache. [image]

Comment: Thanks, today I arrived and the problem was gone, so I am not sure what was causing it, but if it will happen again, I know now what to look for.